# Facebook Issue while creating App getting message not authorized to manage apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create new Facebook User for my Facebook page. who can able to add Facebook Developer Apps to Facebook Page.

How to add Facebook developer app creation permission to Facebook User.

Currently when i have tried to add App with User getting message : - 
Not Authorized To Manage Apps

Thank You

[image]

Comment: can you share a snapshot of this page while you get the error..

Comment: added snapshot of issue